# Java - Binding Available Operations

Tags: java, javafx, bind, pow, bidirectional

I want to bind two `DoubleProperties` by exponentiation. That is I want to do something like:

```
val1.bindBidirectional(2^val2);
```

This does not seem to be possible (see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html)). Why is this and what would be the best way to achieve the same result? Is it making two `ChangeListener`s in a smart way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Bindings` class provides several useful methods for accomplishing this.  One such method is the `createDoubleBinding()` method that allows you to define your own binding code.

What you'll want to do here is bind `val1` using the `Math.pow()` method to calculate the exponentiation. `Math.pow()` takes two arguments: the power factor, and the value to which to apply it:

```
val1.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
                Math.pow(2, val1.get()), val1));
```

Here is an MCVE that demonstrates the concept:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Main {

    private static DoubleProperty val1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private static DoubleProperty factor = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private static DoubleProperty result = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set the value to be evaluated
        val1.set(4.0);
        factor.set(2.0);

        // Create the binding to return the result of your calculation
        result.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
                Math.pow(factor.get(), val1.get()), val1, factor));

        System.out.println(result.get());

        // Change the value for demonstration purposes
        val1.set(6.0);
        System.out.println(result.get());
    }
}
```

When creating the binding, it is important to note that `createDoubleBinding()` accepts a `varargs` argument that allows you to specify all the `Observable` objects that the binding depends on.  In your case, it would just be `val2`, but in the example above, I also have a `factor` property passed through.

The binding value will only be updated if one or more of the dependent properties gets changed.

**A big thanks to [VeeArr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355724/veearr) for helping [solve my own issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199903/how-to-bind-a-value-to-the-result-of-a-calculation/51200294#51200294) while developing this answer!**

Comment: What if I want to create a bidirectional binding?